# Weather gadget Windows sidebar

Tags: javascript, windows, weather, windows-desktop-gadgets

Recently, the sidebar gadget fell off, in which parsing from the site accuweather.com took place. I got the API from the accuweather.com. Is it possible to somehow force this gadget to receive and parse information from the accuweather website directly?

Digging through the files, I found weatherData.js, where I found this:

```
function loadData(units) {
    metric=1;
    if (units=="english")
        metric=0;

    try {
        req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        if (req) {
            req.open("GET", "http://vwidget.accuweather.com/widget/vista4/weather_data_v2.asp?location=" + location + "&metric=" + metric, false);      
            req.send();
            if (req.status == 200) {
                parseData(req.responseXML.documentElement);
            } else {

            }
        }
    } catch (e) {

    }
```

Is it possible to somehow force this gadget to receive and parse information from the accuweather website directly? If yes, what should be entered instead of this link?